# Reading msword from blob file Delphi xe2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have problem with reading blob field from database which contains msword file and save it into file (.doc/.docx). What is moree this works great in Delphi 2010 but in Delphi Xe2 saved files are invalid.This is my code

```
dane.SQLtmp.Close;
 dane.SQLtmp.SQL.Clear;
 dane.SQLtmp.SQL.Add('select wydruk,typ,IdWydruku from wydruki where nazwa=:d0');
 dane.SQLtmp.Params[0].AsString:=name;
 dane.SQLtmp.Open;

 if dane.SQLtmp.RecordCount> 0 then
begin

t:=TMemoryStream.Create;
t.Position:=0;

 TblobField(dane.sqltmp.FieldByName('wydruk')).saveToStream(T);
 T.SaveToFile('C:\FILE'+filetpe);
 t.Free;
end;
```

Saving file into database:

```
        dane.SQLtmp.Close;
        dane.SQLtmp.SQL.Clear;
        dane.SQLtmp.SQL.Add('insert into  Wydruki (Nazwa,Operator,wydruk,opis,typ,rodzaj,podmiot,typsplaty,grupa,podgrupa)');
        dane.Sqltmp.SQL.Add('VALUES (:d0,:d1,:d2,:d3,:d4,:d5,:d6,:d7,:d8,:d9)');


dane.SQLtmp.Params[0].AsString:=NazwaPliku; //File name
dane.SQLtmp.Params[1].AsInteger:=glowny.ID_operator;

    t:=TMemoryStream.Create;
      t.Position:=0;
      t.LoadFromFile(OpenFile.FileName);

      t.Position:=0;

dane.sqltmp.Params[2].LoadFromStream(t,ftBlob);
dane.SQLtmp.Params[3].AsString:=opis;
dane.SQLtmp.Params[4].AsString:=typ;      // file type
// .
// .
// .
dane.SQLtmp.ExecSQL;
```

In Delphi 2010 it worked... :/

Comment: file type, it can be .doc/ docx

Comment: Are you sure that you use the correct file type according to actual data in the blob? Assigning .docx to an actual .doc file, makes it inaccessible with Word, while the other way it still works (when opened with Word 2007, at least).

Comment: Yes I'm sure. While inserting file into database I save also file type in diferet column

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `TBlobField.CreateBlobStream` and copy to a `TFileStream`.

According to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.CreateBlobStream):

> Call CreateBlobStream to obtain a stream for reading and writing the value of the field specified by the Field parameter. The Mode parameter indicates whether the stream will be used for reading the field's value (bmRead), writing the field's value (bmWrite), or modifying the field's value (bmReadWrite).

The **Tip** on the same documentation page says:

> **Tip:** It is preferable to call **CreateBlobStream** rather than creating a blob stream directly in code. This ensures that the stream is appropriate to the dataset, and may also ensure that datasets that do not always store BLOB data in memory fetch the blob data before creating the stream.

Sample code based on yours above:

```
var
  Blob: TStream;
  Strm: TFileStream;
  BlobFld: TBlobField;
begin
  dane.SQLtmp.SQL.Text := 'select wydruk,typ,IdWydruku from wydruki where nazwa=:d0';
  dane.SQLtmp.Params[0].AsString:=name;
  dane.SQLtmp.Open;

  BlobFld := dane.SQLtmp.FieldByName('wydruk') as TBlobField;
  Blob := dane.SQLtmp.CreateBlobStream(BlobFld, bmRead);
  try
    Strm := TFileStream.Create('C:\FILE' + filetpe, fmCreate);
    try
      Strm.CopyFrom(Blob, Blob.Size);
    finally
      Strm.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Blob.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I think You`re right, maybe I should insert them (word files) in diferent way than in D10

Comment: Unfortunately, the effect is the same, the created file has only 1 kb, and is in a strange encoding.
Maybe I should save the file to the database in the same way.
Can you show me how

Comment: That would be a second (separate) question, but you can figure it out. Open the file in a stream, create the blob stream, and copy from the file stream into the blob stream. (It's the exact opposite of the code in my answer; just reverse the streams, and load the file stream from the file on disk.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Interbase components (IB) in Xe2. When I changed them to FireDac'c components my and Yours code works.
That's interesting, recently embarcadero's product have many bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
query.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM something');
query.Open;
query.FieldByName('file') as TBlobField).SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName);
```